# Expose LWC Component on Heroku

Tags: lightning-web-components, heroku

I am receiving error while trying to push the lightning component to Heroku,Can someone please help me resolve this

[image]

Comment: Please share the complete error message.

Comment: scarpment-31395.herokuapp.com request_id=48fe78ec-0490-4145-8b05-cb951eee1668 fwd="183.83.139.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-05T14:50:59.138587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-escarpment-31395.herokuapp.com request_id=44c8c787-052b-41d5-8ada-a4436c8dedae fwd="183.83.139.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-05T14:57:57.932095+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

Comment: @user76829 Please [edit] your post to include the log shown in your screenshot as text.